# How to convert a Django HttpRequest object with data to a Django Rest Framework Request object?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to turn a `django.http.HttpRequest` object that contains JSON POST data into a `rest_framework.request.Request` object, but the data ends up empty.

I was asked to create the `HttpRequest` using the Django Rest Framework's [APIRequestFactory](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#apirequestfactory). So I create it like this:

```
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
factory = APIRequestFactory()
data = {'email': 'test@example.com'}
request =  factory.post('/', data, content_type='application/json')
# also tried using json.dumps(data) instead of just data
```

And then I try to convert it to a `Request` object using:

```
from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
converted_request = Request(request, parsers=[JSONParser])
```

I would expect `converted_request.data` to contain the data from `data`, i.e. `{'email': 'test@example.com'}`. However, when in `print` it, I get `<QueryDict: {}>`:

```
>>> print(converted_request.data)
<QueryDict: {}>
```

The only way I can get the request to contain the data is by setting the `_full_data` attribute after creating the `Request` object:

```
>>> converted_request._full_data = data
>>> print(converted_request.data)
{'email': 'test@example.com'}
```

I'm looking to see if there is a way of populating the request's data without setting the attribute directly. I don't understand why it's not getting populating currently.

Below is the full snippet for easy copy-and-pasting:

```
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
factory = APIRequestFactory()
data = {'email': 'test@example.com'}
request =  factory.post('/', data, content_type='application/json')

from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
converted_request = Request(request, parsers=[JSONParser])

print(converted_request.data)
# <QueryDict: {}>

converted_request._full_data = data

print(converted_request.data)
# {'email': 'test@example.com'}
```

Comment: I don't see any usage of ***updated `Request`*** class. Would you mind adding a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: Thanks for your response @ArakkalAbu. Where I say I "expect `request.data` to contain..." is where I use the updated `request` value. I'll name it something else so it's clearer though. The code is already reproducible. You can just copy and paste it into a Python shell where Django and Django Rest framework is installed.

Comment: What do you see when you execute `print(request.data)` ? where `request =  factory.post('/', data, content_type='application/json')`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the `parsers` need to be instances and not just classes and the data needs to be a JSON string:

```
import json
from rest_framework.test import APIRequestFactory
factory = APIRequestFactory()
data = {'email': 'test@example.com'}
request =  factory.post('/', json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')

from rest_framework.request import Request
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
converted_request = Request(request, parsers=[JSONParser()])

print(converted_request.data)
```